# Can we make anchors in comments more visually distinguishable?

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

I've noticed a few times that people simply don't seem to notice when there is a link in a comment. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797026/angular-ui-directives-as-attribute?noredirect=1#comment38487378_24797026) example. I've seen a few other times as well that some people simply don't notice that there's a link hidden withing the other text.

The text itself has color #444 while the anchor has #4A6B82. They are quite similar. Small dotted underline like the anchors in actual posts get would perhaps help increase visibility?

That would change it from

[image]

To

[image]

Comment: This looks too much like the "power words" feature in some sites, used for advertisement. No thanks.

Comment: Comments are 2nd class citizens on SO, they should not be distracting and draw attention away from posts and answers...wait. Test: [ask]. Meta comments use underline. Maybe it won't be so bad on [so] either?

Comment: FWIW, that link is a *lot* more visible when it hasn't already been followed. Not sure why the "visited" styling is so indistinct on SO, but this isn't the first complaint about it.

Comment: Test: [unvisited url](http://this.is.not/visited) I dunno, looks the same on my client. Toggling :visited in devtools does nothing. Please don't consider my post a complaint though, I personally I have no problem spotting links but I see that others have.