# What's with the underlined links?

Tags: discussion, design, hyperlinks

I see that links on Stack Overflow are now underlined. Was this an intentional change? It looks like SO is going back to the web of 1990s.

Comment: cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/underline-appearing-for-hyperlinks

Comment: Back to the Future!

Comment: dont think its related to welcoming.

Comment: @surajrao, considering the new demographic the 'powers-that-be' seem to be aiming for, I thought the underlined anchor tags were just another way of helping everyone navigate through the site.

Comment: I didn't know that links without decoration were part of the _"web navigation evolution"_. Truly, you learn something new every day.

Comment: @yivi, to my (admittedly small) mind *professional and enthusiastic programmers* can usually identify an unadorned anchor link but I do recall Homer Simpson coded up a pretty sweet web page.

Comment: What? Where? Do you have a screenshot for us?

Comment: @Cerbrus Who needs a screenshot when you have [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372688/whats-with-the-1990s-style-underline-links#comment622039_372688) showing it (linking to a question **with** screenshots) (I do miss the freehand circles here though)

Comment: Oh, I see it now... Cache on my end probably.

Comment: Bugs happen. This is the wrong way to report them. The MSE question linked here is the correct way..

Comment: I for one like being able to identify links in comments before I've had my morning coffee wake-up. Wouldn't call it a bug. But it's probably not part of any welcoming conspiracy either.

Comment: I thought this was funny. But then again, I grew up with the 90s web...

Comment: *to my (admittedly small) mind professional and enthusiastic programmers can usually identify an unadorned anchor link* Didn't 1% of the respondents of the last survey report having a disability that affected their vision?

Comment: if you are so upset by the undeline, you can disable the rendering from your browser options

Comment: @PaulWhite I admit not having checked all browsers. I use Firefox and there is an option under the font color selection.

Comment: @Federico Oh, OK, thanks. I was hoping there would be something similar for Chrome (or Edge), but it appears not. I will stick with my userscript.

Comment: There's a UX question on this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/when-should-hyperlinks-be-underlined

Comment: I'm not sure it will have the same effect now that people don't automatically associate underlining with links. Perhaps it is time for `<marquee>` to make a comeback?

Answer (score 13):

This is intended behavior. We’ve intentionally added underlines to links in posts and comments for contrast and accessibility reasons. Many of our themes’ primary colors don’t deviate much from the text color itself, so we went with the classic way of showing a link’s a link.

Comment: Great! I guess you can close [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265898/957731) then? :)