# Inline tags (inserted by [tag:] markup) are now underlined

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

I've just noticed that tag names inserted by `[tag:tag]` markup ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag)), have become underlined:

> [image: example result]

I've tracked this to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/primary-unified.css?v=947806e43c00`:

```
.post-text a,.comment-copy a {
 text-decoration:underline
}
```

This doesn't happen on other SE sites, and it defeats the purpose of `[tag:]` markup render to look just like tags in questions, so this very much looks like a bug.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372688/4916627

Comment: I also see those lines on MSE: [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313986/388562)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314284/388562)

Comment: It's a bug and will be fixed. Pulling in the info from @AndréKool's link -> *Tags shouldn’t take an underline, nor should previews. Those will fixed in follow-up commits*  ... (saved you a click)

Comment: other links in posts have an underline as well, actually ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug in [Underline appearing for hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/underline-appearing-for-hyperlinks/314284#314284):

> Tags shouldn’t take an underline, nor should previews. Those will fixed in follow-up commits.

and fixed by now.